# Set up JDBC DataSource in LDAP

Tags: ldap, postgresql, oracle, openldap, jdbc

How do I create a JDBC DataSource in an OpenLDAP server?

The problem is that `jdbc/something` is not a valid DN or RDN. But that is the format of the name that you are supposed to use for JDBC DataSources.

This is for an Oracle database, though I would also want to do it for Postgresql and other RDBMSs.

Answer (score 1):

This article has all the steps for connecting a [JDBC Datasource to LDAP Server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm):

**LDAP Syntax**:

`jdbc:oracle:drivertype:user/password@//ldap.domain.com:port/service_name`

Comment: Thanks - but it doesn't explain what this URL format means. In this example: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://ldap.acme.com:7777/sales,cn=OracleContext,dc=com` what does the `sales,` part of the URL mean? It is not a Distinguished Name or Relative Distinguished Name, as far as I know.

Comment: sales is the net service name stored in LDAP

Comment: And where are the credentials?

Answer (score 0):

See [Oracle Database Name Resolution with OpenLDAP](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/LDAP/LDAP_8.shtml).